# Magento Show / Hide Rendered Button when textfield value changes

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Hello everyone I was wondering is it possible to show and hide my rendered button in magento grid when the value of the textfield changes?

[image: Here is my grid]

Column code :

```
$this->addColumn('amount', array('type' => 'input', 'index' => 'amount', 'header' => $this->__('Price'), 'renderer' => 'test/adminhtml_widget_grid_column_renderer_price'));
```

Renderer code :

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $html = parent::render($row);

    $html .= '<button style="display:none;" onclick="updatePrice(this, '. $row->getId() .'); return false">' . Mage::helper('test')->__('Update') . '</button>';

    return $html;
}
```

javascript code :

```
function updatePrice(button, fieldId)
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/updatePrice') ?>', {
        method: 'post',    
        parameters: { id: fieldId, price: $(button).previous('input').getValue() },
        onSuccess: showMessage()
    });

}
```

Comment: You would probably want to handle this in `javascript`, unless the page refreshes everytime you make a change. With that being said, what have you tried already?

Comment: I tried adding an onclick() in my column code but it doesn't work .

Comment: What does your `updatePrice` function look like? Please provide the code

Comment: ok, I'll add it.